# Should I normalize the homography generated by opencv findHomography?

Tags: opencv, homography

When generating a homography using opencvs findHomography I found that sometimes the h<sub>33</sub> != 1.
Should I normalize the homography or just leave it?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can just use it as-is. Because you'll usually be transforming normalized coordinates with it, which themselves will need normalizing after the transformation, there's no need to normalize the homography.